# Error 403 on MapMyFitness API request

Tags: swift, api, alamofire, mapmyfitness

i'n trying to do some request on the `MapMyFitness` API (Oauth2).

I can get my `Authorization Code` with the oauth2 identification, but now i need to request to some route.

Here is the request :

```
Alamofire.request(self.oauthClient.baseURL() + "workout/",
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: nil,
                      headers: authorizationHeader
                   )
        .validate()
        .responseData { [weak self] (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let jsonResponse = try JSON(data: data)            
                    success(items);
                    self?.isLoading = false;
                } catch {
                    self?.isLoading = false;
                    failed(nil)
                }
                break;
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error);
                self?.isLoading = false;
                failed(error)
                break;
            }
    }
```

In the header here is the authorization code like this :

```
"Authorization": "Bearer ***********************************"
```

> Here is the doc about the route API : https://developer.underarmour.com/docs/v71_Workout

Alamofire error:

> responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(403))

Am i missing something ? Thx

Comment: can you share your code for making OAuth2 authorisation? Did you write it in swift3? I tried to find any tutorial for swift3 but theres nothing out there :/

Comment: @pawisoon Make a question with your code and problem and i will try to answer to you.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524410/oauth2-for-mapmyrun-using-swift-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem founded !

If you are using MapMyFitness API you have to use `https://www.mapmyfitness.com/v7.1/` url for the authentification but when you need to request route it's `https://api.ua.com/v7.1/`.

Moreover, you need to add in your header the `"api-key"`.

```
["Authorization": "Bearer ***********************************", "api-key": client_id]
```

and you need to set an user_id in params.

```
var params = ["user" : self.userID, field_set: "time_series"] as [String : Any]
```

These informations are not in the documentation.

Here is my final request :

```
self.authorizationHeader.updateValue(self.clientID, forKey: "api-key")
var params = ["field_set" : "time_series",
              "user" : self.userID] as [String : Any]

 Alamofire.request(self.url + "/workout/",
                          method: .get,
                          parameters: params,
                          headers: self.authorizationHeader
            )
            .validate()
            .responseData { [weak self] (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        let jsonResponse = try JSON(data: data)
                        success(items);
                    } catch {
                        failed(nil)
                    }
                    break;
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error);
                    failed(error)
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```